# Does drunkenness / poisoning / death interrupt ongoing abilities?

Tags: blood-on-the-clocktower

In [Blood on the Clocktower](https://bloodontheclocktower.com/), the [Bad Moon Rising](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Bad_Moon_Rising) edition has a few characters that have ongoing effects. I notice in particular the [Courtier](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Courtier) and the [Pukka](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Pukka), who have abilities that span multiple days.

Normally, drunkenness or poisoning prevents an ability from successfully happening. However, I'm not clear on when happens if these characters become poisoned or drunk while their effects are still happening.

For example:

- The [Courtier](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Courtier) uses their ability on the Mastermind. The next evening, the [Pukka](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Pukka) attacks the [Courtier](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Courtier). Is the Mastermind still poisoned from the [Courtier](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Courtier)'s ability? What about the following evening, after the [Courtier](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Courtier) dies?
- The [Pukka](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Pukka) attacks the Tea Lady, poisoning them. The next evening, the [Courtier](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Courtier) chooses the [Pukka](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Pukka) to poison. Does the Tea Lady die due to the [Pukka](https://wiki.bloodontheclocktower.com/Pukka)'s ability?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, an ongoing ability is suspended / malfunctions while drunk or poisoned. It resumes when sober / healthy again. It goes away (they lose ability) when they die, unless stated otherwise, or implied. If they die while drunk or poisoned, they remain that way, and their ability malfunctions / is gone. (The droison remains if it's static, such as from a Sweetheart. It moves to another player if it's dynamic, such as from a Poisoner.) It's also possible to become drunken or poisoned after dying, which may be temporary or permanent. This affects characters that function after dying, such as the Politician.

In the first example, the Courtier's drinking with the Mastermind stops (they are temporarily sober). The clock keeps ticking, though, and if the Courtier becomes healthy, somehow, before three nights and days pass, their drinking effect resumes. In this case, if they die the next night, their ability / effect is lost (Mastermind remains sober).

In the second example, when the Pukka is drunk, the previously poisoned player does not die yet. They die when the Pukka is sober again, at night, after the sober Pukka chooses the next player. On nights when the Pukka is drunk, their new target is not poisoned, and so they don't die later. The previously poisoned player is temporarily healthy (unpoisoned) until the Pukka becomes sober, at which point, the player is poisoned and dies that night.
The Pukka death happens just after they choose, and usually both occur, or neither works as normal because of drunkenness. The exception is when the Exorcist chooses the sober / healthy Pukka. Then the poisoned player dies, but Pukka does not wake to choose the next victim. If the Pukka is drunk when chosen by the Exorcist, the previously poisoned player, who is now healthy, is on hold until Pukka is sober. Then they are poisoned, and die that night. (The Exorcist does not change how the previous target is affected by the Pukka becoming drunk or sober.) Also, players who are Pukka-poisoned, and about to die to the Pukka, can be protected by another player's ability (e.g. Monk). Then they do not die, and Pukka's poison is removed. A new target who is protected does not get poisoned in the first place, and does not die the next night. Protection is against all (harmful) demon effects, including things like false info from a Vortox.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can determine both effects are still in play for the full duration regardless of the character losing the ability dying. The courtier even lists on the page that it can only be used once per game and getting it off to learn something before you die is a good thing. It however doesn't mention the effects going away when they die.

> You can only use your ability once per the entire game, so time it well! The later you make your choice, the more information you will have the game's state and what characters are in play and causing mayhem. On the other hand, the evil team will be keen to target you as soon as they possibly can, so using your ability early can ensure you get it off and learn something before you die. It's up to you to judge the landscape of your particular game and make your choice!